# How to apply css style to jquery effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a page which contains a list.  I have a button to add a new item to the list. I want to apply JQuery-UI effect to the adding of new item, my problem is when the effect animation is shown, the list item is not styled. See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ec3x9/2/.

You can see that when the user clicks on the create button, the animation of the item is displayed, but the list item text is under the icon since the CSS is not applied.  I want to show the animation of the list item. How do i do that?

Comment: The css is applied, where is not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `>` character between `ul` and `li` in your CSS declarations. What jquery does is wrap your `li` with a `div` element before it does the animations. When that happens, the `li` isn't a direct descendent of `ul` anymore so your styles aren't being applied during the animation.

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/Ec3x9/8/

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the styles don't work properly in IE 7. In FF and Chrome the text is displayed next to the image icon. For IE you can remove the `line-height` or set it to `0` and it should work.

Give that a go and see if it fixes your problem. However, that will break the styles for FF and Chrome. So you will have to add some smarts to make the design work for IE 7 and Chrome/FF.